# Get key value strings from an input string using regex?

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to find key, value pairs in a string using regex ( not sure if it is wise!) here is my string :

```
key1=key1 value key2=key2 value_key3=something key3=key3_value
```

`key1`, `key2`, `key3` are keys.
As you can see, the values can have spaces, and wait...
If you see value of `key2`, it has `key3` in it (`key2 value_**key3**=something`)! Sorry this is how my input is.

Its not over yet. I can have the keys in any order like below :

```
key3=key3_value key1=key1 value key2=key2 value_key3=something
key2=key2 value_key3=something key1=key1 value key3=key3_value
```

Now I want to have a regex that finds me right groups for keys, values so I can later build key value pairs like :

```
key1=key1 value
key2=key2 value_key3=something
key3=key3_value
```

I tried the regex `key1=(.*)key2=(.*)key3=(.*)` , but that works for only first string. If I change the order of keys as in 2nd and 3rd strings , its gone!

Comment: Is underscore always before an embedded key in a value?

Comment: @Bohemian underscore is not necessary always before embedded key, and keys are not actually `key#`, they are real names like say : `myproperty`. I just don't want to post them here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some serious thought, this is indeed solvable, a little tricky :

The most important problem I was facing was the order of keys otherwise the regex `key1=(.*)key2=(.*)key3=(.*)` would have been sufficient.

So I first got the order of keys by collecting them by using Java's `indexOf`

Then I construct the regex runtime using that order , code below:

```
List<String> myPropKeys = new ArrayList<String>();
myPropKeys.add("key1");
myPropKeys.add("key2");
myPropKeys.add("key3");

String input1 = "key1=key1 value key2=key2 value_key3=something key3=key3_value";
String input2 = "key3=key3_value key1=key1 value key2=key2 value_key3=something";
String input3 = "key2=key2 value_key3=something key1=key1 value key3=key3_value";

Map<String, String> propMap = getPropValues(input1, myPropKeys);
propMap = getPropValues(input2, myPropKeys);
propMap = getPropValues(input3, myPropKeys);
System.out.println();



private static Map<String, String> getPropValues( String input, List<String> myPropKeys )
{
     Map<String, String> propValues = new HashMap<String, String>();

     StringTokenizer tokens = new StringTokenizer( input );
     List<String> propKeyList = new ArrayList<String>();
     while( tokens.hasMoreTokens() )
     {
         String token = tokens.nextToken();
         int equalsIndex = token.indexOf( "=" );
         if( equalsIndex != -1 )
         {
             String propertyToken = token.substring( 0, equalsIndex );
             if (myPropKeys.contains(propertyToken))
             {
                propKeyList.add( propertyToken );
             }

         }
      }

      StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
      for ( String propKey : propKeyList )
      {
        sb.append( propKey + "=" );
        sb.append( "(.*)" );
      }

      Pattern p = Pattern.compile(sb.toString());
      Matcher m = p.matcher(input);

      List<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();
      if (m.find())
      {
        for ( int i = 1; i <= propKeyList.size(); i++ )
        {
            values.add(m.group(i));
        }

      }

      if ( propKeyList.size() == values.size() )
      {
        for ( int i = 0; i < propKeyList.size(); i++ )
        {
            propValues.put( propKeyList.get(i), values.get(i).trim() );
        }
      }

       return propValues;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do each key separately:

```
String key1value = input.replaceAll(".*\\bkey1= *(\\S+).*", "$1");
// similar for other keys
```

This extracts everything not a space after "key1=". The key3 example in a value is handled due to the word boundary `\b` required before key's start.

Comment: It gives `k` even for first string.

Comment: Oops. I left out a plus sign. Try the edited version

Comment: values have spaces, it seems you explicitly mentioned no spaces with `\S`. It returns me only `key1` instead of `key1 value`

Comment: @svasa none of your examples have spaces - you should have shown that. If values have spaces I don't see how you can distinguish an embedded key/value in a value from a real key/value. I don't believe your problem is solvable. I would negotiate with the provider of the data to properly deal with the problem by wrapping values in quotes, like `key1="any complex string"`, which can handle anything.

Comment: I did mention that values have spaces. See third line in my question. I understand quoting the values would help, unfortunately the string is the value of an attribute in an xml. But I will try to get right input if I can. Thanks.

Comment: @svasa if that single string is a single XML attribute, then your XML schema is broken. Logically and obviously each key/value should be in the XML as its own attribute. It's not clear what the XML looks like, but I would recommend parsing that using an XML parsing library.

Comment: I know , each key value should be well laid out in the xml schema. But unfortunately it will take days to have the schema changed and make all relevant code changes - not in my control. But I want to deal with single string in single xml attribute if I could.

Comment: @svasa you can't avoid it. It's broken and needs fixing. The time it will take to do it properly is less than the time you'll lose now and in the future dealing with the problem. It's OK to push back. Show the reasons why it's a problem trying to parse it, and that actually it can't be solved. The fault is theirs, not yours.

Comment: It is solvable as far as I can see, could you please look at my answer and see if that makes sense ?

Answer (score 0):

This might get you started:

```
(\w+)=((?:(?!\bkey\w+=).)+)
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/xH3kZ8/1).

In my opinion, the distinction between `key2=key2 value_key3=something` and `key2=key2 value_key3=something` will be the most difficult.
For a better answer, please provide some real input strings.

Comment: Thanks. You can consider `name` for key1, `person` for key2, `age` for key3. properties needn't always start with the word `key`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help you:

```
\b([a-z\d]+)=(.*?)(?=\b[a-z\d]+=|$)
```

It's dependant on keys being constructed by alpha-numeric only though. If **keys** can contain underscores, as the **value** does in your example, it fails. :( And if keys can contain capital letters, the *ignore case* flag must be set.

What it does is to capture a key (letters and numbers allowed), match a `=` and then capture everything up to a new key, or end of line.

[Check it out at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/pE6eI0/1).